# Recovering shapefile with green question marks?

Tags: shapefile, corrupt

I have a shapefile with a green question mark in the ArcCatalog.
The `shp`-extension in the shapefile has `0`Kb size

Is there any way to recover the corrupted file?

Comment: No, it's all gone. What about the other files? Do you have a backup or can you download the files again? Were they working at some stage and have become corrupt? You could try CHKDSK /F and hope you get something back but from personal experience anything you get back is speckled with garbage.